# How to send an email through Terminal AppleScript?

Tags: email, terminal, applescript, clipboard

Is there some way to send an email through Terminal using AppleScript?  It would help if you could also say how to make the content be the Clipboard.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Use `do shell script` with `sendmail` - see `man sendmail`; setting up Postfix (which OSX `sendmail` uses) may be non-trivial, however; http://slashusr.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/enabling-postfix-for-outbound-relay-via-gmail-on-os-x-lion-11/ may get you started.

Comment: As @mklement0 says or you can simply use telnet: http://linuxconfig.org/send-an-email-using-telnet