# How to send an email through AppleScript without the Mail app

Tags: email, terminal, applescript

I need to create an AppleScript program that will send an email **no matter what.**  That means that the Apple Mail app is out of question, because some people do not have Mail set up.  I thought that one way would be to send the email through Terminal, but I have no idea how.  I need some way to send an email through AppleScript without the Mail app.

Comment: Set up a server with some PHP script. Call the PHP website from AppleScript and have the e-mail sent from your server. This is pretty much the only way to send e-mails no-matter-what, but even this solution may fail if people don't allow your app to connect to your server.

Comment: Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418944/how-to-send-an-email-through-terminal-applescript Terminal commands can also be done with a do shell script

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a [python script to send email](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/pythonEmail/pythonEmail.html) and there's applescript code on the page to show how you can call the python script from applescript. Note that you have to supply smtp information to the script, which is essentially the information that you use to setup Mail.app.

So if you wanted a "no matter what" type of solution you would have to include your own smtp info in your code.